# SQL query to fetch data from 2 tables

Tags: python, sql, pypika

I have been trying to write a query where I have majority of information in one table and need information from just one column in the second table. Both table has a column that can be used as connection.

But unfortunately it does not give me the desired output. I am relatively new to coding and used PyPika to write my query. Can you please help?

It fives me "None" for "workflowtracker.COE" which I know there is data and many duplicate logs

Please find the query below

```
   q = Query.from_(workflowtracker).join(activitylog).on(
    activitylog.RequestId == workflowtracker.RequestId).select(workflowtracker.COE, activitylog.RequestId,
                                                               activitylog.SubjectLine,
                                                               activitylog.ResourceName, activitylog.ResourceEmail,
                                                               activitylog.GPN, activitylog.ExecutionDate,
                                                               activitylog.Status,
                                                               activitylog.TotalTimeTaken).where(
    (activitylog.Status == "In Progress") & (activitylog.ExecutionDate == excecutiondate))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please use this:**

```
workflowtracker, activitylog = Tables('workflowtracker', 'activitylog')
q = Query
     .from_(workflowtracker)
     .join(activitylog)
     .on(workflowtracker.RequestId == activitylog.RequestId)
     .select(workflowtracker.COE, activitylog.RequestId,
               activitylog.SubjectLine,
               activitylog.ResourceName, activitylog.ResourceEmail,
               activitylog.GPN, activitylog.ExecutionDate,
               activitylog.Status,
               activitylog.TotalTimeTaken)
    .where(
    (activitylog.Status == 'In Progress') & (activitylog.ExecutionDate == excecutiondate)
    )
```

Comment: What are the changes you are suggesting? Can you please edit your answer to make that more clear and explain why it would solve the problem? Also, applying some indentation and line breaks like the author of the question did will make your code more readable.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).